# How to set diplayName of a firebase User while using Phone Authentication

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating an android massaging app where I am implementing Firebase Phone Authentication. When I am creating PhoneAuthOptions, I am not seeing any method to set User's displayName, and after the verification completion I need User's name to save it with phone number into Database. While setting up phoneNumber of the User, is there any I can set displayName of the User?

```
     val options=PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
         .setPhoneNumber(number)
         .setTimeout(60L,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .setActivity(this)
         .setCallbacks(callbacks)
         .build()
     PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
     Log.d("MSG","Auth started")
  }
```

Here is the OTP activity code, I want to get User's displayName also, when I am getting currentUser's phoneNumber. and I want store displayName in the place of uid.

```
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this){ task->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    val pref : SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    val editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = pref.edit()
                    editor.putBoolean("LogedIn", true).apply()
                    mDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    mDBRef = mDB.getReference()

                    val phoneNumber = mAuth.currentUser?.phoneNumber!!
                    val uid = mAuth.currentUser?.uid!!
                    mDBRef.child("Users").child(phoneNumber).setValue(uid)

                    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user is signed in, you can set their display name by calling `updateProfile` on their `User` object as shown in the documentation on [updating the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile). From there:

```
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser

val profileUpdates = userProfileChangeRequest {
    displayName = "Jane Q. User"
    photoUri = Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg")
}

user!!.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.")
            }
        }
```